# How to route React application login page if server returns 401 error code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React application that splitted into many small components. I have five main pages that users can navigate;

I'm using nested routing as you can see below;

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/login">
            <PageLogin />
        </Route>
        <PrivateRoute path="/app">

                <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path={`/app/dashboard`}/>
                        <Route path="/app/user">
                            <PageUsers ></PageUser>
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="/app/edit">
                            <PageEdit />
                        </Route>
                        <Route path="/app/manage">
                            <PageManage/>
                        </Route>
                        <Route path='/app/j3'>
                            <PageJ3></PageJ3>
                        </Route>
                    </Switch>
                </Router>

        </PrivateRoute>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

I have defined the /app route as a private route. I want only authenticated users to reach this pages. 
I have defined private route function component as below;

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
            this.isAuthenticated = cookieCheck() ? true : false;
            return (
                <Route
                    {...rest}
                    render={({ location }) =>
                        this.isAuthenticated ? (
                            children
                        ) : (
                                <Redirect
                                    to={{
                                        pathname: "/login",
                                        state: { from: location }
                                    }}
                                />
                            )
                    }
                />
            );
        }
```

It redirects the users to login page if *isAuthenticated* is false.
That logic works. But I also have detail pages inside these main navigation pages. For example *PageEdit* has a page inside called *PageEditDetail* . This detail page opens when user clicks an object inside the page. It makes an api call using fetch. I'm loading the header with token that I've received on login. If the token is expired server returns **401 error** and of course page doesn't show anything from user but I want the page to be redirected to login page in this case.

I've tried adding the below script to callback of the fetch method but it didn't worked;

```
if (fetchedRes.status === 401) {
                    return <Redirect to='/login' />
                }
```

How can I redirect the React application to login page from child component according to a parameter ?

Comment: have you tried `history.push('/login')` ?

Comment: How can I push to history inside the child component of the child component ?

Comment: if `PrivateRoute` is a function then `this` would be null, right ?

Comment: if (fetchedRes.status === 401) {
                    return history.push('/login')
                }